# How to get the store name from EntityManager for my entity?

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I have an application which is capable of storing my `entities` in different `RDBMS` stores.

I am doing the basic `create,retrieve,update,delete` using my `EntityManager`. The sample code goes like this

```
EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "App" );

  EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
  entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

  Employee employee = new Employee( ); 
  employee.setEid( 1201 );
  employee.setEname( "Gopal" );
  employee.setSalary( 40000 );
  employee.setDeg( "Technical Manager" );

  entitymanager.persist( employee );
  entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

  entitymanager.close( );
  emfactory.close( );
```

My `EntityManager` is configured like this

```
<persistence-unit name="App">
    <description>Hibernate EntityManager Demo</description>
    <class>com.baeldung.hibernate.pojo.Movie</class> 
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/moviecatalog"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit> 

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("App");

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

***I wanted the info that my entity Employee is getting stored in mysql at a particular place in code where multiple entities are available.***

Is there any API through `EntityManager` by which I can do this ?

Comment: I can't really understand what do you need.Do you want to see the SQL statements executed by hibernate?

Comment: yes I am doing that. I just want to know to which store my entity is persisting at runtime.